# element not visible but present - protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, automated-tests

I have div with buttons which I would like to click.
Elements are visible when a user moves the mouse cursor on div. 
How to click buttons? I can move the cursor on div and then I will get visible buttons.
Is another way to click buttons without move cursor?
automation tests in protractor.

Comment: Maybe look at [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: Is this question about programming at all? Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

> When you hover on hidden div it's not hide until you leave mouse from
>   it so you can click any button and etc. you can use this below code i
>   hope it help's you.

```js
$(".mark").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(".icontent").stop().show(1000);
    }
})
$(".m1").on({
    mouseout: function() {
        $(".icontent").stop().hide(1000);
    }
})

$(".icontent").on({
 mouseover: function() {
        $(".icontent").stop().show(1000);
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1">


<a href="#" class="mark">hover anchor</a>
<div class="icontent" style="display: none;">
  <p>
    Test Content......
  </p>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="mark btn btn-danger">Button 1</a>
</div>  
</div>
```